# The PostgreSQL database cannot start after modifying the IP

Tags: postgresql

The following is the operation process:

```
[root@freelab ~]# su - postgres
Last login: Sat Jul  4 10:16:58 EDT 2020 on pts/1
-bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_ctl -D /postgres -l logfile start
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ date
Sat Jul  4 10:35:13 EDT 2020
```

But the log does not seem to be updated accordingly

```
[root@freelab log]# tail -f postgresql-Sat.log
2020-07-04 09:23:14.930 EDT [1832] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1840) exited with exit code 1
2020-07-04 09:23:14.930 EDT [1835] LOG:  shutting down
2020-07-04 09:23:14.943 EDT [1832] LOG:  received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files
2020-07-04 09:23:14.943 EDT [1832] LOG:  parameter "data_directory" cannot be changed without restarting the server
2020-07-04 09:23:14.944 EDT [1832] LOG:  configuration file "/postgres/postgresql.conf" contains errors; unaffected changes were applied
2020-07-04 09:23:15.052 EDT [1832] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When restarting the server with a specific logfile (see your restart command: `/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_ctl -D /postgres -l logfile start`) you need to look at that specific logfile, not at `postgresql-Sat.log`.

Moreover, this line in the previous log shows that you modified the data directory:

> ```
> 2020-07-04 09:23:14.943 EDT [1832] LOG:  parameter "data_directory" cannot be changed without restarting the server
> ```

Presumably `log_directory` is relative to the data directory, so after this change you need to look at the **new location** now to find the new logs.
From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html):

> **log_directory** (string)
>
> When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter determines the directory in which log files will be created. It can be specified as
> an absolute path, or relative to the cluster data directory. This
> parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server
> command line. The default is log.